# How to make <hr> extend underneath ordered list numbers?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a list created with ng-repeat, and under each list item I have a horizontal rule.

```
<ol>
   <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-dblclick="deleteItem(item)">
     {{item}}
     <hr>
   </li>
</ol>
```

However, the area that is occupied by the numbers (decorators?) blocks the horizontal rule from extending within.

[image: Example Issue]
[image: Inspect Element]

Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using:

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
    /* other CSS */
}
```

Which brings the list-markers within the `<li>` elements.

Or simply use `border-bottom` in place of an `<hr />` element.